# How to split up a jsp file into different child subfile which will be shared by multiple parent files

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

Recently I came across a situation which is described as follows :

I have a struts action class for instance say A. Let say the corresponding jsp file is show.jsp
   Now i have a requirement to show some extra stuff in the jsp file so I extended the struts action class and the new class called as B but i am using the same show.jsp. But i passed an extra parameter to show.jsp and i check in the show.jsp like following to show appropriate content

```
         if(popo){ 
             @include "popo.jsp".
         }else{
             @include "original content present before the requirement."
         }
```

Recently I have one more requirement like new struts action class C which also use show.jsp to render the html but the new requirement and the previous requirement share somewhat similar html content.So now i code looks like

```
          if(popo || jojo){ 
             @include "popo.jsp".
         }else{
             @include "original content present before the requirement."
         }
```

but inside popo.jsp i again check like

```
              if(jojo){
              }else{
              }
```

because i want not all things from popo to be displayed for jojo

I would like to know if it's a good practice to do this kind of stuff.It's getting messy each day. Is there any way i can make things cleaner.?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic is better managed in a controller, not a JSP.  You could have different displays, using SiteMesh or Tiles, and let the controller pick the appropriate one based on conditions.

Another way to manage it is with jQuery.  Use it to hide/show a `<div>` based on data.

Comment: If i had different displays then there would be code duplication because there are things which are common b/w either 3 of them or may be 2 of them.